# cannot import name 'ops' from 'keras'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/generative/ipynb/pixelcnn.ipynb) example Colab notebook from Keras.io, but When I run the first cell (imports section) I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'ops' from 'keras' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py)` error. As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076277/cannot-import-name-ops-python) thread, I have already tried uninstalling and installing TensorFlow and Keras, and also I have tried upgrading TensorFlow and Keras.

Comment: try `pip install keras-nightly`

Comment: You need keras 3 for that code, and you probably are not using keras 3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrage to keras 3. Use this
pip install --upgrade keras

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).